# Is it possible to use protobuf-net Serializer and at the same time the respective *.proto file?

Tags: protobuf-net

I have a .NET type, which is attributed with neither ProtoContract nor DataContract. In addition, not all of its state need to be proto-serialized.
Can I define a .proto file for it, but at the same time use some kind of a Serializer to serialize it as though it is attributed with ProtoContract?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a third option, `[XmlType]` and `[XmlElement(Order=n)]` can be used... but I don't think that is what you mean ;p

In "v2", this is indeed possible. You don't need to define a .proto - you can simply tell it what to do at runtime, for example:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
model.Add(typeof(SomeType)).Add("Foo", "Bar", "Blip");
```

now store `model` somewhere (and re-use it), and use `model.Serialize(...)` and `model.Deserialize(...)`. The above configures `SomeType` to serialize `.Foo` (as field 1), `.Bar` (as field 2) and `.Blip` (as field 3). There are of course many more ways of doing this for more fine-grained control.

It will generate (as first needed) a serializer (via IL emit, so very fast) that works with your types as expected.

There is a downloadable "v2" dll, but it needs updating - I have done a lot of fixes in the last few weeks. I will try to refresh this dll later today, or you can build from code.

Comment: Hi Marc. Two questions. In the project site you say that for production v1 is to be used. Do you mean now that v2 is ready for production? Because, this is where I want to use it. Second, if it is possible, can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063273/is-it-possible-to-deserialize-a-private-property-using-protobuf-net-in-silverli? Thanks.

Comment: @mark - short answer "yes" (in fact, we are "live" with it at stackoverflow); longer answer "there are some v1 features that you probably don't need that need implementing before it is 'final' - see my blog as soon as I write it"

Comment: I do not mind building from the source. Should I checkout the trunk at http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk?

Comment: @marc - So, you do not recommend building from the source?

Comment: @mark - I don't object at all... simply, I haven't made any changes in the last few minutes... I've been busy writing the blog.